# Does a baby go for the most hard-to-get out of two presented objects?

Tags: reference-request, experimental-psychology, decision-making

I'm searching for some reliable source for the following experiment:

A baby is placed in front of two identical fruits, one of which is covered by a transparent box. I think I've read that babies statistically prefer the boxed fruit and try to reach it first, after which they investigate the more easily accessible one.